# How can I restore the original /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/php.ini file for Plesk 10.12?

Tags: plesk

So I got stupid and ran the PHPMNG script and accidentally whacked the php.ini file that Plesk uses internally.  Now, all the *MNG commands are throwing errors.  I tried to manually recreate the file with the right include paths, but I have no idea what else I'm missing.

Any good ideas on where I can get the 'psa/admin/conf/php.ini' file to make this version work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upload /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/php.ini from 10.4 to http://pastebin.com/dpAaJSXH